# How can I correct the calling URL?

Tags: java, servlets

I am making a basic login based project using Servlets in Eclipse IDE. I have made a jdbc file that first validates the user from the database and then redirects the page to the welcome page, that is an html file.
Everything is saved in their default folders. But everytime I try to execute my project, I get this error - [image: Http Status 404 - /Diary/welcome]. The called URL here is `localhost:8080/Diary/welcome` but the called URL should be `localhost:8080/Diary/welcome.html`.
How can I solve it?

**Login.java**:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Login {

    public static boolean validate(String user,String pass){
        boolean status=false;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Diary", "root", "root");
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM trial WHERE user=? and pass=? and authorized=?");
            ps.setString(1,user);
            ps.setString(2,pass);
            ps.setString(3,"yes");
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                status=true;
            }

        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}

        return status;
    }
}
```

**LoginServlet.java**:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();        
        String user=req.getParameter("user");
        String pass=req.getParameter("pass");
        if(Login.validate(user, pass)){
            out.println("you are successfully logged in!");
            req.getSession().setAttribute("login", "true");
            req.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
            res.sendRedirect("welcome.html");

        }else{
            out.println("<p>Sorry, username or password error</p>");
            req.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").include(req, res);
        }

        out.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly redirecting to the 'welcome.html' file. There must be an interceptor in your project that removes the '.html' part.

Comment: how can I detect that interceptor? or how can I correct this?

Comment: i detected the interceptor. Thanks for the help.